# Creating Constructor Methods

Tags: java, file, methods, constructor

There is a classroll program that I am working on with multiple classes. In the classroll class I have a construct method "ClassRoll (String f) {" that is suppose to ....

Read the class roll data from the input file f, creates Student objects for each of the students and adds them to the ArrayList of students.
The input file contains the course title on the first line. The data for each student appears on a separate line consisting of first name, last name, score1, score 2, and score3 separated by at least one space.

Below I will show the classroll class and the main method where I have tried to call that constructor. Every time I run the program I keep getting an error coming from that constructor. I need help on how to create that constructor correctly to do what it needs to do because my attempt at it doesn't work. Any help at all would be appreciated thank you.

```
public class ClassRoll {

private ArrayList<Student> students = new ArrayList<Student>();
private String title;
private String filename = "data.txt";


 ClassRoll(String f) {      
    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
    String inpFileName = kb.next();
    File inpFile = new File(inpFileName);

    boolean firstline = true;
    while(kb.hasNextLine()){
        if(firstline){
            title = kb.nextLine();
            firstline = false;
        }
        else{
            String fName = kb.nextLine();
            String lName = kb.nextLine();
            int score1 = kb.nextInt();
            int score2 = kb.nextInt();
            int score3 = kb.nextInt();

            students.add(new Student(fName, lName));

        }
    }


}


void Remove() {
    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("What is the Student's first name?");
    String fName = kb.next();

    System.out.println("What is the Student's last name?");
    String lName = kb.next();

    Student s = new Student(fName, lName);

    for (int i = 0; i < students.size(); i++) {
        if (s.compareTo(students.get(i)) == 0) {
            students.remove(i);

        } else {
            System.out.println("Error: Student is not in Class");
        }

    }

}

void Display() {
    DecimalFormat fmt = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
    System.out.println("\t\t\t" + title);

    double classAverage = 0.0;

    for (int i = 0; i < students.size(); i++) {
      Student s = (Student) students.get(i);
      System.out.print(s.toString());
      System.out.println("\t" + fmt.format(s.getAverage()));
      classAverage = classAverage + s.getAverage();
    }
    System.out.println("\t\t\t" + fmt.format(classAverage /      
       students.size()));


}

void Add() {
    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("What is the Student's first name?");
    String fName = kb.next();

    System.out.println("What is the Student's last name?");
    String lName = kb.next();

    System.out.println("What is the Student's first score?");
    int score1 = kb.nextInt();

    System.out.println("What is the Student's second score?");
    int score2 = kb.nextInt();

    System.out.println("What is the Student's third score?");
    int score3 = kb.nextInt();

    Student s = new Student(fName, lName);

    for (int i = 0; i < students.size(); i++) {
        if (s.compareTo(students.get(i)) == 0) {
            System.out.println("Student already in class");
        } else {
            students.add(s);
        }
    }
}

void changeScore1() {
    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("What is the Student's first name?");
    String fName = kb.next();

    System.out.println("What is the Student's last name?");
    String lName = kb.next();

    System.out.println("What is the Student's first score?");
    int score1 = kb.nextInt();

    Student s = new Student(fName, lName);

    for (int i = 0; i < students.size(); i++) {
        if (s.compareTo(students.get(i)) == 0) {
            s.setScore1(i);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Error: Student is not in Class");
        }

    }

}

void changeScore2() {
    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("What is the Student's first name?");
    String fName = kb.next();

    System.out.println("What is the Student's last name?");
    String lName = kb.next();

    System.out.println("What is the Student's first score?");
    int score1 = kb.nextInt();

    Student s = new Student(fName, lName);

    for (int i = 0; i < students.size(); i++) {
        if (s.compareTo(students.get(i)) == 0) {
            s.setScore2(i);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Error: Student is not in Class");
        }

    }

}

void changeScore3() {
    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("What is the Student's first name?");
    String fName = kb.next();

    System.out.println("What is the Student's last name?");
    String lName = kb.next();

    System.out.println("What is the Student's first score?");
    int score1 = kb.nextInt();

    Student s = new Student(fName, lName);

    for (int i = 0; i < students.size(); i++) {
        if (s.compareTo(students.get(i)) == 0) {
            s.setScore3(i);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Error: Student is not in Class");
        }

    }

}

public void find() {
    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("What is the Student's first name?");
    String fName = kb.next();

    System.out.println("What is the Student's last name?");
    String lName = kb.next();

     Student s = new Student(fName, lName);

    for (int i = 0; i < students.size(); i++) {
        if (s.compareTo(students.get(i)) == 0){
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }
}

public void sortAverage() {
    for (int i = 0; i < students.size() - 1; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < students.size(); j++) {
            Student s1 = (Student) students.get(i);
            Student s2 = (Student) students.get(j);
            if (s1.getAverage() < s2.getAverage()) {
                students.set(i, s2);
                students.set(j, s1);
            }
        }
    }
}

public void sortNames() {
    for (int i = 0; i < students.size() - 1; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < students.size(); j++) {
            Student s1 = (Student) students.get(i);
            Student s2 = (Student) students.get(j);
            if (s1.compareTo(s2) > 0) {
                students.set(i, s2);
                students.set(j, s1);
            }
        }
    }
}

public void save() throws IOException {
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(filename);
out.println(title);
for (int i = 0; i < students.size(); i++) {
    Student s = (Student) students.get(i);
    out.println(s.toString());
}
out.close();

 }}
```

MAIN METHOD

```
public class Assignment4 {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter the name of the input file ->");
    String fileName = input.next();

    ClassRoll c = new ClassRoll(fileName);


    prompt();
    System.out.print("Enter a command --> ");
    String ans = input.next();

    while (!(ans.equalsIgnoreCase("q") || ans.equalsIgnoreCase("quit"))) {
        if (!(ans.equalsIgnoreCase("a") || ans.equalsIgnoreCase("Add")
                || ans.equalsIgnoreCase("s")|| ans.equalsIgnoreCase("average")
                || ans.equalsIgnoreCase("n")|| ans.equalsIgnoreCase("names")
                || ans.equalsIgnoreCase("r") || ans.equalsIgnoreCase("remove")
                || ans.equalsIgnoreCase("f") || ans.equalsIgnoreCase("find")
                || ans.equalsIgnoreCase("d") || ans.equalsIgnoreCase("display"))) {
            System.out.println("Bad Command");
        } else {
            switch (ans.charAt(0)) {
                case 'a':
                    c.Add();
                    break;
                case 's':
                    c.sortAverage();
                    c.Display();
                    break;
                case 'n':
                    c.sortNames();
                    c.Display();
                    break;
                case 'r':
                    c.Remove();
                    c.Display();
                    break;
                case 'f':
                    Student s = c.find();
                    if (s == null) {
                        System.out.println("Student not found");
                    } else {
                        System.out.println(s.toString());
                    }
                    break;
                case 'd':
                    c.Display();

                    break;
            }
        }
        prompt();
        System.out.print("Enter a command --> ");
        ans = input.next();
    }
    c.save();
    System.out.println("Thank you for using this program");

}

public static void prompt() {
    System.out.println("Enter one of the following commands");

    System.out.println("a or Add to add a student in the classroll");

    System.out.println("sa or average to sort the students based on their average");

    System.out.println("sn or names to sort the students based on their last names");

    System.out.println("r or remove to remove a student from the class roll");

    System.out.println("f or find to find a student in the class roll");

    System.out.println("d or display to display the class roll");

    System.out.println("q or quit to exit the program");
}
```

}

STUDENT CLASS

```
public class Student {

private String fName;

private String lName;

private Exams scores;

Student(String fn, String ln) {
    fName = fn;
    lName = ln;
    scores = new Exams();

}

public void setScore1(int sc) {
    int score1 = 0;
    score1 = sc;

}

public void setScore2(int sc) {
    int score2 = 0;
    score2 = sc;

}

public void setScore3(int sc) {
    int score3 = 0;
    score3 = sc;

}

public String toSring() {
    return String.format("%-10s %-10s %4.2f\n", fName, lName, scores);
}

public double getAverage() {
    return (scores.getScore1() + scores.getScore2()
            + scores.getScore3()) / 3.0;
}

public int compareTo(Student s) {
    String name1 = lName + "  " + fName;
    String name2 = s.lName + "  " + s.fName;

    if((lName + "  " + fName).compareTo(s.lName + "  " + s.fName)> 0)
        return 1;
    else if ((lName + "  " + fName).compareTo(s.lName + "  " + s.fName)< 0)
        return -1;
    else return 0;
}
}
```

Comment: Please share the error message and Student class

Comment: @Ahmed I added the student class

Comment: @Ahmed    Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException  at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:864)  at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)  at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2117)  at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2076)  at classroll.ClassRoll.<init>(ClassRoll.java:41)  at classroll.Assignment4.main(Assignment4.java:23)

Comment: you are getting exception while reading a file not creating an object.                       String fName = kb.nextLine();
                String lName = kb.nextLine();
                int score1 = kb.nextInt();
                int score2 = kb.nextInt();
                int score3 = kb.nextInt();

Comment: @Ahmed the problem is in the constructor classroll correct? That's problem I have,  the way I tried to make it read a file isn't working

Comment: @Ahmed I know that's the problem. But how would I fix that?

Comment: No it's not in the constructor. Share your file also please

Comment: for score1,score2 and score 3, you are attempting to read the int value directly. but it is not integer , so the input is mismatching. Debug and find what value is coming there and try to fix. And based on your code, I don't think you are reading those values from inputfile, but you are reading it from console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This exception is thrown by the Scanner

> Thrown by a Scanner to indicate that the token retrieved does not
>   match the pattern for the expected type, or that the token is out of
>   range for the expected type.

Please check your input file. It will solve your problem.

Your data must be line separated.

Code snippets

```
Scanner kb = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(new File("d://app//test.txt")));
boolean firstline = true;
        while(kb.hasNext()) {
            if (firstline) {
                title = kb.nextLine();
                firstline = false;
            } else {
                String fName =kb.next() ;
                String lName = kb.next();
                int score1 = kb.nextInt();
                int score2 = kb.nextInt();
                int score3 = kb.nextInt();

                students.add(new Student(fName, lName));
            }
        }
```

Comment: COP2210                                                                           John    Doe                  50    60    70                                       Marco  Boyle              50    60    73                                      Eric     Munzon           45  100    90                                 Marry   Able               95  100  100                                   Jack           Smith      100  100  100                            Elizabeth   Gomez      100  100  100

Comment: That's the file. And check the input file where? Sorry I'm a beginner programmer

Comment: Your file is in one line with space or in a new line. Plus your scanner object is not referring to file.

Comment: What do I have to do then? I know I'm reading from the file incorrectly but that's why I posted the question I've tried to fix it myself but I don't know how to correctly do it

Comment: would do you any idea what I could change? So it can read the file correctly

Comment: Please see my code in answer post... It will now help you.

Comment: thank you for all your help. Is there anyways I could ask you one more question?